# Error al querer levantar proyecto de laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, xampp, github

hola me surgio un problema al querer levantar mi proyecto localmente de laravel, dicho proyecto yo lo habia levantado dias anteriores y hoy al querer ver unos cambios que hice en el codigo me salio el siguiente error en la consola al querer levantarlo

```
Jose@Jose-PC MINGW32 /c/xampp/htdocs/web-imsur
$ php artisan serve
Error creating winpty: ConnectNamedPipe failed: Windows error 232
```

alguna idea que pueda estar pasando ?, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me pasó hace un par de años, no sé si sea tu caso pero en el mío fue el antivirus Avast, por alguna razón al programa WinPTY no lo reconocía como "completamente válido" porque su ejecución es a través de scripts (no por acción directa del usuario) y lo ejecuta en modo sandbox por seguridad. Lo que puedes hacer es desactivar temporalmente tu antivirus o agregar a WinPTY en su lista blanca.

Comment: ese archivo que mencionas el WindPTY donde lo encuentro en el caso de que sea el antivirus

Comment: `winpty` es un utilitario de otros programas, es probable que la ubicación cambie de un equipo a otro así que mi ruta quizás no te sirva, pero prueba entrando a tu línea de comandos y ejecuta el comando `where winpty`, te mostrará la ubicación de este en tu equipo